# android studio version 3.1.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

After updating my android studio to 3.1.1
I found the error in the picture.
Before I updated android studio everything was fine.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SetTimeActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private  int TIME_IN_MINUTES ;
    private EditText et ;
    private Button mButtonStartPause;
    private Button mButtonReset;
    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
    private boolean mTimerRunning;
    private long mTimeLeftInMillis;
    private long mEndTime;
    DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager;
    ComponentName componentName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_time);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setTimerMenu_et);
        mButtonStartPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.set_btn);
        devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        componentName = new ComponentName(SetTimeActivity.this, Controller.class);
```

[image]

Comment: Did you do a Gradle Sync?

Comment: I had the same issue but it got away on restating Android Studio. I think you should restart your Android Studio.

Comment: try this : go to file > invalidate caches / restart > invalidate and restart

Answer (score 1):

Try the following and check if it works :

1. Try to invalidate caches and restart. For this :

> File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart

2. Open up your command line and perform a manual gradle build :

   ./gradlew clean assemble
3. Make sure you have the following in your build.gradle :

   ```
   compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:{latest}"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer but I got it Now,
So they add dependencies to the gradle
and we have to replace "compile" with "implementation", something like this ,
you can find everything you need in this URL :

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html?utm_source=android-studio#new_configurations